# SWM enumeration in the lpc812 nxp mcu's

Tags: arm, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

there are a SWM capability in the lpc812 MCU which enable developers to assign each peripheral(like SPI,UART & ...) to a desire GPIO pin ,but some special peripherals only assign to some fixed pins in default state,In LPCOPEN for assigning new peripheral to these pins you must first disable their fixed pin's function with :

```
Chip_SWM_DisableFixedPin(SWM_FIXED_VDDCMP);
```

which **SWM_FIXED_VDDCMP** is member of Below enums

```
typedef enum CHIP_SWM_PIN_FIXED    {
    SWM_FIXED_ACMP_I1 = 0,  /*!< ACMP I1 */
    SWM_FIXED_ACMP_I2 = 1,  /*!< ACMP I2 */
    SWM_FIXED_SWCLK   = 2,  /*!< SWCLK */
    SWM_FIXED_SWDIO   = 3,  /*!< SWDIO */
    SWM_FIXED_XTALIN  = 4,  /*!< XTALIN */
    SWM_FIXED_XTALOUT = 5,  /*!< XTALOUT */
    SWM_FIXED_RST     = 6,  /*!< Reset */
    SWM_FIXED_CLKIN   = 7,  /*!< Clock Input */
    SWM_FIXED_VDDCMP  = 8   /*!< VDD */
} CHIP_SWM_PIN_FIXED_T;
```

And this is chip's datasheet:
[image: LPC812's Datasheet]

As you can in ACMP1 & ACMP2 , they are equivalent of GPIO 0.0 & GPIO 0.1
but for other e.g. SWM_FIXED_VDDCMP it's GPIO 0.6 and 9th member of enum. 
as you can see above for example : `Chip_SWM_DisableFixedPin(SWM_FIXED_VDDCMP);`
disabled VDDCMP fixed function from pin 6 and then we can assign new peripheral to this pin,But in the datasheet VDDCMP is pin6 but in the enum it is equal to 8,why ?

Comment: ...and the question is?

Comment: why pin of GPIO is different from enum members?

Comment: Well, have you tried looking at the code which _uses_ those values? (Hint: for any answer beyond "because they are", you'd need to ask the hardware designer...)

Comment: OK,I edit my question to clear my mind.

Comment: As I said, the enum definition is trivially explained by just looking at `Chip_SWM_DisableFixedPin()` itself. _Why_ the PINENABLE0 register is laid out that particular way is essentially unanswerable.